# How can I align decimals in Google Documents editing?

Tags: google-docs, text-formatting

I'm using a regular document, might have been uploaded as a .wps file.

Could the list I'm working on be converted to a spreadsheet without retyping, or copy/paste?

Also, trying to make two columns on a page?

Answer (score 1):

Google Documents does not (yet) have the 'Decimal tab' that Excel and other word processors have though judging by Accounting format in Google Sheets it might be 'on its way'. Instead adding a right tab-stop has the same effect - provided the decimals are of consistent length (number of digits):

[image: right tab-stop]

You are not likely to be able to convert word processing data to spreadsheet format without either retyping or Copy/Paste.

To split into columns go to Format > Columns and, in your case, choose two columns.